Is work always done to achieve motion against an opposing force?
Good day guys,
I was taking a look at Atkins book on physical chemistry. I had a look at his definition of work and got me quite confused:

“Work is done to achieve motion against an opposing force”.

From my understanding, work can be done to achieve or change the motion of an object. If an object is at a constant speed (in frictionless space) and I apply force to change its direction or speed, I am not doing work against any opposing force. This leads me to think that the given definition in the book is wrong or not written appropriately. And of course I usually assume that if I think it’s the books fault, then it’s most probably my fault. How can I best interpret the definition given by Atkins?
Thank you guys.

@Ghoster very sorry about the typo, completely missed it and got caught up with work. Thanks to Amit for fixing it.

That’s an ambiguous definition. But a book on physical chemistry is probably not the best choice for a definition of work

That does not appear to be a definition to me. Maybe a corollary or a consequence.

You are right, and the book is... unclear.
The most general definition of work is $W = \int \vec{F} \cdot d \vec{l}$, where $F$ is the force applied to an object and the integral is over the path along which the object is displaced; as you rightly note, there is no opposing force involved at all! The only thing you need to know to calculate the work being done on some system is the force applied to it, and the path that it follows.
The definition given in the book is therefore confusing at best, and for many situations not correct. However, since the book is on physical chemistry, the author might have a particular type of system in mind (and probably not a ball accelerated in vacuum).
If instead you think of a gas confined to a volume with a movable piston, then to push the piston (and compress the gas) you need to apply a force that exceeds the pressure of the gas.  Because of this opposing force, you cannot move the piston without doing work - the force you apply must be at least $F = pA$ where $p$ is the pressure of the gas and $A$ the area of the piston where the force is applied. If the pressure were zero, then it would be possible to move the piston without doing any work, just like in the case of a ball in vacuum. For this limited type of system, it therefore does make some sense to think of work as 'being done to overcome an opposing force'.
I don't know much about physical chemistry, but my guess would be that this is the kind of system the author had in mind.

Figure: Gas in cylinder with movable piston. From https://physicslabs.ccnysites.cuny.edu/img/tutorial-ideal-gas-piston-1.jpg

There is always a counterforce. All forces in nature come in pairs as a result of interactions between pairs of objects. For example, two charges can act on each other with a pair of forces, or two masses, or the piston and the ideal gas in your example. It is impossible to find an example where A would act on B with a force but B would not act on A with the same but oppositely directed force. This is a trivial consequence of momentum conservation. Therefore whenever you act on something with a force and move it, you are doing it agains a counterforce, so nothing wrong with the definition.

I don't disagree with Newton's third law, of course, but I doubt that that is what Atkins had in mind. After all, the reaction force acts on you, while the work done on some system depends only on the forces that affect the system. It seems much more sensible (to me) to talk about an opposing force if there is actually an opposing force acting on the system.

@Vosoni Ultimately there may not be a clear answer to this question because the definition is too vaguely worded. I think I understand your interpretation, which would make the definition correct, though (I think) unclear and rather confusing. However my best guess would be that Atkins had a particular type of system in mind, e.g. a gas in a cylinder, and that the vague wording follows from that. At least the OP has now been offered several possible interpretations. :)

@Jakobs KS - You misunderstand Atkins' definition. He means the work done by you against a force that acts on you. This work will be of course equal to the work done on the system by the force acting on that system. The two forces (the one acting on you and that acting on the system) are related by the Newton's 3rd law. Atkins' definition is perfectly fine for any system. Because of the conservation of energy, the work you spend is equal to the energy the system gains. He means the first energy, which you spend to overcome a force.

@Vosoni I maintain that I don't think that is what Atkins means. I now actually found the relevant except from his book. He writes (11th edition, page 34): "Work is done to achieve motion against an opposing force. A simple example is the process of raising a weight against the pull of gravity", and a few sentences later "An example of doing work is the expansion of a gas that pushes out a piston". He does not mention Newton's third law anywhere in the book (according to the index).

@Vosoni If he had intended a general definition of work, he would probably just have given the usual definition $W=\int F dx$
, but he probably had a particular system in mind more relevant to chemistry. Still, I agree that your interpretation could justify his original definition (and for the same reason, I didn't down vote your answer)- but I don't think that it's a very helpful way to think about work, and it seems to be quite hard to apply in various common cases, e.g. an external electric field doing work on a charge

Static electric field cannot do work on a charge, I addressed this example in the chat. This would contradict momentum conservation. The source of that field (capacitor of some sort) would do work and experience the force against which that work is done. The field only mediates the interation between charges.

@Vosoni just to reiterate, we all agree that forces come in pairs related via Newtons third law. Of course it doesn't matter, then, if you define work via the "action" or "reaction" force. But that is clearly not what Atkins means, and therefore not, I think, what this question was about.


This leads me to think that the given definition in the book is wrong
or not written appropriately.

I tend to agree with you, depending on what the book means by “opposing force”. If it is only referring to some external force acting on the object, the definition is wrong, as illustrated in the following example.
Suppose I use a pole to push a box with a  constant 100N force a distance of 1 m. I do 100 J of work. In one case there is a kinetic friction force between the box and the floor that opposes the motion of the box. In the other case the floor under the box is frictionless with me standing on a part of the floor with sufficient static friction so I don’t slip (remember I’m using a pole to push the box). I do the exact same amount of work in both cases (though the motion of the box will be different due to the net work on the box being different).
On the other hand, if the book is referring to the equal and opposite internal (to the pole-box system) 10N force the box exerts on the pole, per Newton’s third law in both the friction and non friction cases, then I suppose the definition wouldn’t be technically wrong. However I question its relevance as a definition and consider it better suited as a statement.
Hope this helps.

When you apply a force to a mass to change its velocity, the mass is acting on you with an opposing force that is equal and opposite in direction (3rd Newton's law), so your work is done to overcome that force. The definition is a bit unusual, but it makes sense.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
